# Nginx, API (https + redirect) and Vue.js application on subdomain

Tags: ssl, nginx

I need to configure nginx config for three (possibly four) server running on one physical server.

I have Rails API and Rails also do server rendering html pages + a separate Vue.js application.

Basically, I need two nginx servers for Rails with https protocol, server configs look like this (it's working :)):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/example/shared/tmp/sockets/example-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.me;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /home/deploy/apps/example/current/certs/cert_chain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/deploy/apps/example/current/certs/private.key;


  root /home/deploy/apps/example/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;

  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 30;
}
```

So here I need to add Vue.js application server, and here is where thing are getting mess up and stop working (it's config for Vue in history mode):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name backoffice.example.me;

  root /home/deploy/apps/example-front;

  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
  }

  location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html last;
  }

  location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
  }
}
```

Is there any way to make it work on one physical server?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: It's redirects to https protocol

Comment: Do you have a hsts policy?

Comment: sorry, what is it? I've updated DNS records and add subdomain name if this is what you are talking about.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security